# How to check class in a policy's scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, policy, pundit

Project is with Rails + Pundit. `Fruit` class has two subclasses:

- `Tropical < Fruit`
- `Temperate < Fruit`

In `fruit_policy.rb` I got this:

```rb
class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.is_near_equator
        scope.where(class: Tropical)
      else
        scope.where(class: Temperate)
      end
    end
  end
```

The `class` check above gives me:

```rb
NameError (uninitialized constant Fruit::Tropical...
_________________________________________^^^^^^^^^
```

Is it possible to check the class within a scope in a policy? If so, how?

Comment: how about `scope.where(class: ::Tropical)`?

Comment: Gave this a shot and it results to the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implemented the subclasses with [STI](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance-sti) and followed Rails naming conventions for database columns then you can scope the query to a subclass by filtering on the `type` columns with the desired class name as a string:

```
def resolve
  if user.is_near_equator
    scope.where(type: 'Fruit::Tropical')
  else
    scope.where(type: 'Fruit::Temperate')
  end
end
```

Comment: Completely missed to think of this, had to do `type: 'Fruit::Tropical'` / `type: 'Fruit::Temperate'` to make it work correctly.